# Decode displaying text in asp.net mvc drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have tried many ways to decode my Html.DropdownListFor text. Can anyone give me a better solution

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID, Model.EntityName)
```

Here Model.EntityName is selected list. 
I created EntityName as

```
new SelectList(EntityName , "ID", "Text");
```

here I want to decode displaying text. 
because if the text contains `&lt;&quot;&gt;`like string it displays as same in my drop down. So I want to display it as `<">`

Thanks

Comment: First of all if its a single item why would you want to create a dropdownlist for it?

Comment: DropdownListFor expects a `SelectList` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. How is `Model.EntityName` populated? What is `EntityName` in this:  `new SelectList(EntityName , "ID", "Text");`? You need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: here `EntityName` is `SelectList` type variable, It is coming from Complex Type I created with SQL server stored procedure

Comment: If `EntityName` is already a `SelectList`, then why do you need this? `new SelectList(EntityName , "ID", "Text");`

Comment: That seems dangerous (XSS).

Comment: Why would you have `<` and `>` in your display text? Like all `HtmlHelper` methods (except `.Raw()`) the value will be encoded and you cannot change that